# How to scrape business summaries from Yahoo finance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape only the business summary of a company from yahoo finance page eg https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL
Business summary is the information below the company profile on the webpage on the right side.
I can see that it is defined in a class of 'p'. but it is quite nested in divs.  I am not able to navigate to it using beautiful soup.

I tried this

```
article_text = ''
article = soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'businessSummary Mt(10px) 0v(h) 
Tov(e)'})
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
for element in article:
    article_text += '\n' + ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
print article_text
```

but it is not returning me the paragraph text.

Thanks in Advance. I was not able to paste the source inspect of the webpage. Not able to format to paste it here in readable way.

Comment: The class `businessSummary Mt(10px) 0v(h) Tov(e)` is not there in the source of that page..

Comment: Is the business summary the description of the company under the "profile" tab?

Comment: The one you look for is within `script` tag. There are several `script` tags available in that page. Try `soup.find_all("script")[-3]` which will fetch you the third last `script` in which you will get necessary information you are trying to parse. If you think of any alternative then try using any browser simulator like `selenium`.

Comment: There's a big react json object on that page, you need to grab it with regex and parse it with json.

Comment: @SIM Can you please guide me more on selenium?

Comment: Yeah sure [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233325/unable-to-get-a-dynamically-generated-content-from-a-webpage). An exact same question with two solutions.

Comment: Thank you @SIM , this helped!